# How can I link back to Term's page using Node Auto Term [NAT]?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using [NAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/nat) on a content type called Profile configured as follows in the picture below. I've been able to use this in great ways in some views.

[image]

I see that when I do a `dpm($var['node'])` from `theme_preprocess_node($vars)` that I see a NAT entry in the debug output.

[image]

My question is how do I properly grab this `tid` and automatically create a link to the taxonomy term's page (`/taxnonmy/term/503`)?

Cross reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/2291797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I've come but it's still sort of hack-ish.

```
 function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {

        $termid = "none";
    if (
        isset($vars['element']['#object']->nat) &&
        $vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'body' &&
        $vars['element']['#object']->type == 'instructor_profile'
        )
    {



    list($termid, $value) = each($vars['element']['#object']->nat);
    $vars['term_id'] = $termid;

    /* Use EFQ to determine how many nodes may have this taxonomy attached
    to it. I'm only interested in the count()*/
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_related_instructor_mention', 'tid', $termid)
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
    $count = $query->count()->execute();


    /* If there is information ($count>0), then show. If no links
    don't worry about it */
    if($count > 0) {

        $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] =
        "<div class='only-small'>" .
        "<p><a href='/taxonomy/term/$termid'>More News</a></p>" . "</div>" .
        $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] ;
    }


}

    }
```